# How to make auto adjustable DIV width to 100%?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with dynamically generated DIVs.
Those DIVs are placed inside the other "parent" DIV (`class="container"`). I need to display 2 DIVs equal in width per row (now it is 940px, which makes 100% of the width).

But sometimes there are DIVs with a long content inside and they need more space. So I cannot restrict the width to a fixed number. I use `min-width: 460px;` only.

If I have one DIV left on the last row (it can happen) I need this DIV to have be stretched to 960px (100%) always. And this condition is not always the same. Sometimes there are only one DIV and sometimes two (at the end of the page). And I need CSS to "understand": if there is a space after the DIV the DIV should be stretched to the full width (960px), and if there is another DIV on the right hand, both DIVs should be 480px and in the same row.

I have also tried `:last-child`, but it did not work for me.

To see the abstract in code here is a small listing what I have:

```
<style>
    .container {
        width: 960px;
    }
    .content {
        float: left;
        min-width: 480px;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="content" style="background-color: Orchid;">Hi! I am content</div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: NavajoWhite;">Hi! I am content</div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: Chartreuse;">Hi! I am content.. Very loooong-loooong content.. Too many words. Too many.. More and more and more... And even more for you! Believe me, I will grab all 100% of the container DIV</div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: Aquamarine;">Hi! I am a last content</div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox:

```css
.container {
  margin-bottom:20px;
  width: 960px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.content {
 /* flex-basis: 50%; // in my case it was odd */
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content" style="background-color: NavajoWhite;">Hi! I am content</div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color: Chartreuse;">Hi! I am content.. Very loooong-loooong content.. Too many words. Too many.. More and more and more... And even more for you! Believe me, I will grab all 100% of the container DIV</div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color: Aquamarine;">Hi! I am a last content</div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content" style="background-color: NavajoWhite;">Hi! I am content</div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color: Chartreuse;">Hi! I am content.. Very loooong-loooong content.. Too many words. Too many.. More and more and more... And even more for you! Believe me, I will grab all 100% of the container DIV</div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color: Aquamarine;">Hi! I am a last content</div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color: orange;">Hi! I am a last content</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you. Flex-basis was odd. The rest works like a charm!